# Setting UISplitViewController's preferredDisplayMode whilst pushing onto detail navigation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a standard `UISplitViewController`, with navigation controllers in both its master and detail panes. Most of the time, the split view controller has its `preferredDisplayMode` set to `.allVisible` so that both the master and detail are visible.

When I push a particular view controller onto the detail navigation stack, I'd like to hide the master pane so that the user has more of a 'full screen' view. To implement this, I tried changing the `preferredDisplayMode` to `.primaryHidden` in `viewWillAppear` of the detail view controller, and changing it back in `viewWillDisappear`. However, this results in a really bad animation, and incorrectly placed views at the end of the transition.

[image: Incorrect animation]

I'm unsure how to fix this. I've tried changing the display mode at different times, placing the call to change the `preferredDisplayMode` into an animation block (although it's implicitly animated anyway), and asking the view controller's view to lay itself back out. It looks a little better in an animation block, and the views end up correctly placed, but the animation is still kind of weird and jumpy.

So, how do fix the animation and achieve the appearance I'm looking for?

I put together a [minimal sample project](https://cloudup.com/cDHMcMEN1zu) to demonstrate the problem. Simply click the 'Push' button in the detail view controller to present the view controller that reconfigures the split view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `prepareForSegue` in the DetailViewController. This will change the `.preferredDisplayStyle` of your `UISplitViewController` **before** presenting FullscreenViewController, with smoother animations.

In storyboard, the select the show segue from the 'push' button to the FullscreenViewController and set it's identifier (I always use the name of the destination ViewController.) Then in DetailViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "FullscreenViewController" {
        self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
    }
}
```

For a quick fix when navigating 'back' to DetailViewController, I added

```
self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
```

to `viewWillAppear` in DetailViewController. I typically use a delegate to pass data between view controllers, and set the display mode there. Hope that helps.

Comment: I am using a similar approach (actually, I placed `self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible` in viewWillDisappear of the viewController I'm presenting full screen, but I've tested your approach in viewWillAppear and works the same). My issue is I still have the problem of the original poster with the wrong width of the detailView controller at the end of the transition back from the "full screen" view: in my case a tableView in the detail appears to be too large and part of the cells are offscreen until I scroll, then the tableView "adapts" its size. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: So, I found a workaround to the issue I explained in my previous comment: with a custom back button in the VC I'm presenting "full screen", I'm able to call `self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible` before `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` and this solves the incorrect width of the detailVC after the dismissal of the full screen one is completed.